# Slow loading of firebase images in website

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to load images into my website. I'm loading approximately 51 MB of data but it's taking a lot of time to load it (52 secs) precisely on 10 MBPS internet speed.
The method which I'm using is typing the firebase image url in href .
Kindly help me with this problem and also if there exists efficient way of doing it please let me know.

Comment: need some sort of code to see how you are loading the images into your site

Comment: <div class="Image-Loader">
    <div class="Slide-ShowImageView">
        <img src="FIREBASEIMAGEURL?alt=media&token=999644fb-8596-2b57-4e3a" class="img-view" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>